# Incomplete install and I cannot see part of the hard disk

Tags: installation, dual-boot, hard-drive

I had tried to install Ubuntu 10.10 near a Windows7 in a 64 system. The installation was suppose to be 512Gb left for Win and 512Gb for Ubuntu. The installation hanged and on restart windows sees only his 512 partition. When I try again to install Ubuntu I only see the windows partition.

How can I recover the lost partition and install Ubuntu there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing this software 'PARAGON PARTITION  SERVER' and scan this hdd and see if it sees the other partition, if that 512gb partition is seen format it in NFTS format

Comment: thanks. I was doing the same with another one. Mini tool partition recovery. If this fails I'll try yours.

Comment: You can use the Disk utility on the LiveCD as well.

Comment: Ok but don't worry one way or the other you will get the partition back. When reinstalling usb try a live usb as it is faster and safer than a live CD

Comment: it did worked with the disk utility from the cd.